# LWGJL. Graphics blinking

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

I init OpenGL in my `lwgjl` application in this way:

```
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION)
glLoadIdentity()
glOrtho(0, displayWidth, 0, displayHeight, -1, 1)
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)
glClearColor(clearColor.r, clearColor.g, clearColor.b, clearColor.a)
```

When I'm drawing text using `slick` library and `UnicodeFont` or `AngelCodeFont` (by `font.drawString(...)`). Text is drawing (flipped vecrtical), but other image, which is behind text is blinking.

How to avoid blinking and draw text correct? May be something is wrong with OpenGL initialization? I tried also `glDisable(GL_LIGHTING)` and `glEnable(GL_BLEND)` with `glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA)`. Nothing changed. :(

Comment: Are you using double buffering?

Comment: Yes, I invoke Display.update() for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved! Next code works for me:

Init OpenGL:

```
    glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)
    glDisable(GL_LIGHTING)

    glEnable(GL_BLEND)
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA)
```

Draw text:

```
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)
    font.drawString(x, y, text, color)
    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)
```